# Dynamically change layout on mouse action

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I am developing a React application.
The problem statement is to show 4 videos(2 videos per row) and when user clicks on any video, that video should maximize and rest 3 videos should go in next row like this[image] and when clicked again it should take default 2x2 layout.

How can I achieve this by changing layout dynamically on mouse click? what is the CSS styling for it?

Currently 2x2 layout is implemented here [codesandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/relaxed-chaum-dbj6y?file=/src/App.js).

Thanks,

Comment: You need to post a [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)...

Comment: Yeah , codesandbox link is attached

Comment: You can use `grid` layout in the container. Here you can read more about [grid](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/)

Comment: grid seems to be feasible solution. I will try it